# How do I remove the white line under the nav bar

Tags: html, css, web

I'm using the [Creative](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/creative/) theme from start bootstrap and I want to remove the white line below the nav bar. How do I do that?

HTML:

```
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Start Bootstrap</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-default {
  background-color: white;
  border-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.05);
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s;
  transition: all 0.35s;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
  color: #F05F40;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #eb3812;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-toggle {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #222222;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navbar-default .nav > li > a,
.navbar-default .nav > li > a:focus {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #222222;
}
.navbar-default .nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav > li > a:focus:hover {
  color: #F05F40;
}
.navbar-default .nav > li.active > a,
.navbar-default .nav > li.active > a:focus {
  color: #F05F40 !important;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-default .nav > li.active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav > li.active > a:focus:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: white;
  }
  .navbar-default .nav > li > a,
  .navbar-default .nav > li > a:focus {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  }
  .navbar-default .nav > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .nav > li > a:focus:hover {
    color: white;
  }
  .navbar-default.affix {
    background-color: white;
    border-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.05);
  }
  .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
    color: #F05F40;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
  .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #eb3812;
  }
  .navbar-default.affix .nav > li > a,
  .navbar-default.affix .nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #222222;
  }
  .navbar-default.affix .nav > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default.affix .nav > li > a:focus:hover {
    color: #F05F40;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if I've posted all the code here. If not you can always refer to the website and download the code. Thank you!

Comment: the white line is probably added by the bootstrap. you may wanna inspect the element to see which css rule is causing the issue

Comment: how do I know? I'm totally new to coding

Comment: google how to inspect html element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The white line is defined by the bootstrap css. So, You need to overwrite it's css. Like this:

```
.navbar-default{
   border:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this also:

```
 .navbar-default {
        border: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old.

but this is the original code on the nav-tabs

```
    .nav-tabs {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dee2e6;
}
```

all you have to do is add this n your css sheet

```
.nav-tabs {
    border-bottom: none ;
}
```